# Как узнать логин и пароль пользователя в Active Directory .

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

Как я могу получить логин и пароль пользователя, который уже есть зареестроватний в LDAP. То есть  он должен открыть мою программу(Пишу на JAVA), а она уже автоматически проверить является ли этот пользователь, и взять  все возможные данные о нем.
Я искал разные варианты, но так и не нашел, слышал можно Kerberos токеном, или же запросом к LDAP-a. Если у кого-то была такая проблема отзовитесь.

Comment: Пусто пусто не пропускает?

Comment: @nick_n_a нет ) не в этом проблема

Comment: Имя пользователя, должность, mail телефон вы узнать сможете, пароль боюсь что нет, разве что какие-нибудь хеши.

Comment: @nick_n_a можно , но нужно что б пользователь был  авторизованный

Comment: Не правильная формулировка вопроса. Нужно было спросить про то, как приложение на Java может проверить правильность логина и пароля в Active Directory.

Comment: @gimntut в яблочко!

Comment: если вопрос стоит таким образом, то надо просто попросить пользователя ввести имя и пароль и пытаться залогиниться с этими данными в LDAP. Если получится, то значит тот, который надо, пользователь, если нет, значит имя или пароль неправильные.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы Active Directory так легко отдавал бы пароли любых пользователей, то им бы давно уже никто не пользовался бы. Вы можете достать любую другую информацию о пользователе, если имеете соответствующие права доступа, но не пароль.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте apache-вскую либу для работы с ldap. 
Получить можно ХЭШ пароля, для чего нужно сформировать правильную строку запроса на поиск объектов типа user. Далее из объекта дергаете значение поля с паролем, который как правило закодирован SHA1. Кодируете введенный пользователем пароль и сравниваете.